# where is .gvimrc and .vimrc file up to date?

Tags: vim

I just started  to learn vim. The Macvim wiki and Vim wiki and the vim built-in help document all said that the `.gvimrc` and `.vimrc` is located in `~/.gvimrc` and `~/.vimrc`. I think the information it is outdated.

I use Mac OS X 10.10.1, and downloaded the newest version of Macvim from the official site. When I type `ls -a` in the terminal in my home directory, it lists:

```
.           .dropbox        Downloads
..          .idlerc         Dropbox
.CFUserTextEncoding .python_history     Library
.DS_Store       .viminfo        Movies
.Trash          Applications        Music
.bash_history       Desktop         Pictures
.bash_profile       Documents       Public
```

There is no `.gvimrc` or `.vimrc`

Comment: The docs are telling you that `vim` looks for those files in those locations and uses them if they are found. That doesn't mean that they are already on your machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there isn't one already in your home directory, you can simply create one with

`vim ~/.vimrc`

and populate it with your config preferences.

Once in Vim, you can see a list of all scripts your vim session is referencing with the `:scriptnames` command. Your .vimrc should be around the top.

Comment: thanks a lot,the `:scriptnames` really help me, by the way, I find both the `.gvimrc` for Macvim and `.vimrc` for vim shipped with Mac hide in a more deep path, if I create my `.gvimrc` or `.vimrc` in my home directory, will it overwrite the default one or just and the differences?

Comment: No problem! You're welcome to accept this as the accepted answer if I've solved your problem. :) Yes. If you have a .vimrc defined in your home directory it will "overwrite" (that is, not read from) the system defined one. (I think in the case of MacVim it's in the MacVim folder under Applications?)

Answer (score 3):

Many distributions do not provided `~/.vimrc` or `~/.gvimrc` by default. Instead they rely on `/etc/vimrc` (or `/etc/gvimrc`) for system-wide defaults. `~/.vimrc` and `~/.gvimrc` allow you to configure **your individual** preferences without affecting others.

Here is an example ~/.vimrc

```
hi Comment term=bold ctermfg=lightblue guifg=lightblue
noremap Y y$
"
" Set the default tab behavior 8-4 (coding):
"
" DUMMY press - ctrl+v mapseq
" i.e. for 8-4: ctrl+v then \[shift]T
"
set noexpandtab tabstop=8 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4
" set noexpandtab tabstop=8 softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2
"
" Set key-mappings to allow changing between tab profiles easily
"
" Normal, 8-4 "T":
"
map \T <Esc>:set noexpandtab tabstop=8 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4<CR>
"
" Mini tabs, small "t":
"
map \t <Esc>:set noexpandtab tabstop=8 softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2<CR>
"
" Map Minimal tabs "M" 4-4 "m" 2-2 and full "f" 8-8
"
map \M <Esc>:set noexpandtab tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4<CR>
map \m <Esc>:set noexpandtab tabstop=2 softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2<CR>
map \f <Esc>:set noexpandtab tabstop=8 softtabstop=8 shiftwidth=8<CR>
"
" compile, run and comple to assembly
"
map \g <Esc>:!mkdir -p bin; gcc -Wall -Werror -o bin/%< % <CR>
map \r <Esc>:!./bin/%< <CR>
map \s <Esc>:!mkdir -p asm; gcc -O2 -masm=intel -S -o asm/%<.asm % <CR>
```

Answer (score 2):

the `.vimrc` file under your HOME need to be created by yourself. If you come from a fresh installed vim.

Depends on your requirement, a vimrc file with some configurations may look like:

https://github.com/sk1418/myConf/blob/master/common/.vimrc